# How to simplify g-mail addresses using regular expressions in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I would like to simplify a gmail address in Hive by removing anything unnecessary. I can already remove "." using "translate()", however gmail also allows anything placed between a "+" and the "@" to be ignored. The following regular expression works in Teradata:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('test+friends@gmail.com', '\+.+\\@' ,'\\@');
```

gives: 'test@gmail.com', but in Hive, I get:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments
>   ''\@'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to
>   execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)
>   on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace@131b58d4 of
>   class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace with arguments
>   {test+friends@gmail.com:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,
>   +.+@:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, @:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 3

How do I get this regular expression to work in Hive?

Comment: Are you familiar with relevant laws in all the jurisdictions you plan to operate in? In Canada, for example, I'm pretty sure you're required to use precisely the email that users give you. That means you can't strip out periods, `+foo`, etc.

Comment: @Chris It depends on what he's using this for. If he's sending to the modified address you have a point. If he's just trying to remove duplicates from a list, this could be OK.

Comment: Regardless of what the law requires, sending to a different address than someone gives you is just plain wrong. Users use these suffixes for a reason, you shouldn't ignore them.

Comment: This is the "find duplicates" use case, so regulations aren't an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `@` in regular expressions. Try:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('test+friends@gmail.com', '\+[^@]+@' ,'@');
```

You should also use `[^@]+` rather than `.+` so the match stops at the first `@`. Otherwise if there are multiple addresses in the input, the match will span all of them.

Comment: This doesn't work for me:
hive> select REGEXP_REPLACE('test+friends@gmail.com', '\+[^@]+@' ,'@');
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''@'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text ....... (similar error)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hive, does `@` have special meaning to it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any special meaning to it, though I could be missing something. I guess this is part of the reason for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

select REGEXP_REPLACE('test+friends@gmail.com', '[+].+@' ,'@');

or

select REGEXP_REPLACE('test+friends@gmail.com', '\+.+@' ,'@');

Does the trick. Teradata and Hive seem to have significant differences in how they process regular expressions.